# Primary Network has a Unknown Interface which led PXE Installation Failed

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, pxe

We see an Unknown Interface in Ubuntu Installer(OS: Ubuntu 16.04 Server) that cause we installed ubuntu failure via kickstart script.

[image]

So we would like to know does anyone meet this situation before?

As far as we know, this unknown interface is Redfish 1.0.1. LAN-Over-USB device. Would that be possible to check if this device have been supported by the current Ubuntu kernel?

Another question is if the device doesn't have inbox driver, could we change the order to this situation below to make the auto installation worked?

1. enp97s01: Inter 82599 10Gigabit Network Connection
2. enp33s0f3u1u2c2: Unknown Interface

And any specific rule to determine this network interface order?

Thanks.

Josh

Answer (score 0):

An interface designation such as enp97s01 isn't created until the correct driver has joined with the hardware, The fact that the LAN-Over-USB device has an interface designation, namely enp33s0f3u1u2c2, suggests that there *is* a working kernel driver.

I believe that the notation *Unknown Interface* simply means that the description Redfish 1.0.1. LAN-Over-USB device is either not present or not readable from the silicon. This happens in a few cases with networking hardware that I've seen. It never, in and of itself, keeps the device from working.

> could we change the order to this situation below to make the auto
>   installation worked?

In this context, I believe the TAB key allows you to select whichever device you prefer and to which the ethernet cable is attached.